# Akka Streams - Understanding when and how materialisation works

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

An app that I am developing requires/gives the users the ability to create and define arbitrary streams at runtime. I understand that in Akka streams in particular

Materialisation = Execute or Run

My questions

1) Should materialisation for a stream be done only once? i.e if it is already materialised then can I use the value for subsequent runs?

2) As said above, maybe I misunderstood the term materialisation. If a stream has to run, it is materialised each time?

I am confused because in the docs, it says materialisation actually creates the resources needed for stream execution. So my immediate understanding is that it has to be done only once. Just like a JDBC connection to a database. Can someone please explain in a non-akka terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a stream can be materialized multiple times. And yes, if a stream is run multiple times, it is materialized each time. From the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.12/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#defining-and-running-streams):

> Since a stream can be materialized multiple times, the materialized value will also be calculated anew for each such materialization, usually leading to different values being returned each time. In the example below we create two running materialized instance of the stream that we described in the `runnable` variable, and both materializations give us a different `Future` from the map even though we used the same `sink` to refer to the future:
>
> ```
> // connect the Source to the Sink, obtaining a RunnableGraph
> val sink = Sink.fold[Int, Int](0)(_ + _)
>
> val runnable: RunnableGraph[Future[Int]] =
>   Source(1 to 10).toMat(sink)(Keep.right)
>
> // get the materialized value of the FoldSink
> val sum1: Future[Int] = runnable.run()
> val sum2: Future[Int] = runnable.run()
>
> // sum1 and sum2 are different Futures!
> ```

Think of a stream as a reusable blueprint that can be run/materialized multiple times. A materializer is required to materialize a stream, and Akka Streams provides a materializer called `ActorMaterializer`. The materializer allocates the necessary resources (actors, etc.) and executes the stream. While it is common to use the same materializer for different streams and multiple materializations, each materialization of a stream triggers the resource allocation needed to run the stream. In the example above, `sum1` and `sum2` use the same blueprint (`runnable`) and the same materializer, but they are the results of distinct materializations that incurred distinct resource allocations.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. But I am confused because creating actors is costly and if materialisation happens each time a stream is run, wouldn't it be costly? As I understand streams use a single actor underneath for sequential components and dedicated actors for async components. Or is it something taken care by the runtime and we dont have to worry about performance part.

Comment: [Operator fusion](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.12/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#operator-fusion) is the default behavior. Whether using operator fusion or defining asynchronous boundaries performs better depends on the situation. This [blog post](http://blog.colinbreck.com/maximizing-throughput-for-akka-streams/) is helpful in understanding the implications of both approaches.

Comment: @JeffreyChung I am slightly confused by what you means as in both sum1 & sum2 are different futures. Don't they provide the same value?